# localization of database

Tags: android, sqlite, locale

In my application i am making two different databases for two different languages ,,both by databases are in assets folder,  based on the locale it should take that particular database. not sure how to implement it, I though to put database name in string folder for different languages , but how to pass that name as DB_NAME is not sure. Would like to know how to localize the database when i have two different databases in assets folder. below is my code

```
public class MatDatabase {

    protected static final String TAG = "ability Database";
    protected DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;
    protected SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ability.sqlite";
    protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    protected final Context mCtx;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // The Android's default system path of your application database.
        private final String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + "/data/com.in.android.ability/databases/";

        private final static String DB_NAME = "ability.sqlite";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

        private final Context myContext;

        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

            this.myContext = context;
            //myContext.getResources().getString(R.string.dbname);
        }


        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if (dbExist) {
                // do nothing - database already exist
            } else {

                this.getWritableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                } finally {
                    this.close();
                }
            }

        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try {
                String NAME = myContext.getResources().getString(R.string.dbname);
                String myPath = DB_PATH + NAME;
                File dbFile = new File(myPath);
                return dbFile.exists();

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // database does't exist yet.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (checkDB != null) {

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            this.getWritableDatabase();

        }}
```

Comment: If you have 2 different databases, just choose and copy one of them basing on the current locale. What else?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how do u get the other language DBName ..as you can see in my code i am mentioning the DB_Name="ability.sqlite".how to pass the other DB here.

Comment: say you have a db named "ability_en.db" and a db named "ability_de.db", just select one or another and copy it giving a new name "ability.db" during the copy.

Comment: Can u show some code how to give the name while copying

Comment: Here: `String myPath = DB_PATH + NAME;` NAME is the final name of the database. Here: `InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);` replace DB_NAME with the localized db name you want to get from time to time. Simple.